# Python3 Won't print anything from file

Tags: python-3.x

My code is:

`with open('<filename>') as File:
    for line in File:
        print(line)`

Should work (as far as I read the tutorial well). `<filename>` is filled with (ascii)text, and there is enough in the file to imagine the program would at least return something. It doesn't. I have checked if the working folder for the program was right with `print(os.getcwd())`, which it was, and also checked the existence (if the program could see it) with

`if os.path.exists('cfplotter.com'):
    print("yes")
else:
    print("no")`

It prints 
`<path>
yes` (where `<path>` is the expected path).

What do I do wrong? I use Python 3.4.0 btw.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you call [`open()`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/functions.html#open) you should get in the habit of specifying how you're opening the file - for reading, writing, both, etc. Try:

```
with open("myfile.txt", "r") as f:  # "r" is read mode
    for line in f:
        print(line)
```

and see if that works. If not, please update your question with any errors that you are getting, and verify that you have access to the file. Instead of playing around with `os.path.exists()` and `os.cwd()`, try passing the full path of the file to the `open()` command.

Comment: When the mode is not specified, wouldn't python default to 'r'?

Comment: @warunsl - It should, which is why I phrased it the way I did (`you should get in the habit of ...`). The OP's code should work just fine, and if it can't find the file it should be throwing an error. Other than that, I'm not sure exactly what's going on, just stabbing in the dark.